# Firewall Replication

Tags: cisco-asa, redundancy, failover

If I have two datacenter sites that are considered redundant to each other. Is it possible to sync firewall configuration from the primary to the backup? What is the best way to keep both firewalls updated at the same time?

If so, what is required?

---

Equipment used:

- Main DC

  - Two Cisco ASA's running 8.2.5
- Remote DC

  - Two Cisco ASA's running 8.6

The link between the two DC's is a a L2 link connecting both DC cores. The ASA's connects to each core.

Comment: You've tagged this as "cisco-asa" - are you using ASA's in your datacenters? The answer is going to be dependent on which firewalls you're using as well as the version of software and licensed features running on them. Please include this information in your question.

Comment: How far apart are the Data Centers in question?  [Keep in mind that you should try to keep your latency under 10ms for best failover performance](http://puck.nether.net/pipermail/cisco-nsp/2011-March/077578.html)

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

We have a similar setup but with two sets of 8.2(5) and we have used an in-house script to detect config changes to the primary pair, change the necessary details to make it connectable in the second DC and push the config to the second firewall pair and finally reboot.

This only works for us because the second FW pair is completely passive whilst a failover isn't active.

All the script basically does is pull the active config, run a regex to replace the management details with those of the second pair, a regex to replace the SNMP, hostname etc. Once done it TFTP's the config to the second pair and initiates a reboot.

Comment: If you want I can upload it to github or something for reference.

Comment: Script solutions are probably the best you can do to keep four firewalls in some rough stage of configuration sync... although this is architecturally limited to an active/standby DC scenario

Comment: That would be great! Or email dannyvanzee@gmail.com

Comment: Can I ask why you have the FWs reboot after config changes? Why wouldn't moving it to running config work?

Comment: We've always done it as some of the changes can't easily be carried out when just over-writing the running-config.

Comment: Just for reference, I recently saw a 9.2.1 presentation with inter-site clustering.  While not specifically for this use case, it is useful for active/active site firewalls.